# Matrix Conditional formatting : why when column has 0 then its all red? Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I set up Color Scale  no color from lowest value to red color for highest value.
But if I filter data and column "Losses" have values $0 then for some reason the whole column becomes red.

Is any way how can it make it with "No color" if all the values are 0's?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like your minimum and maximum values are zero here so it can't distinguish between them. Does setting the minimum to the number 0 help at all?

Comment: Setting the minimum to the number 0 did not help as well.  But if I set min 0 and max any number then seems like it works.

Comment: Yep. If max is something else, then it can distinguish the two conditions.

Comment: Got it. thank you for pointing to right direction.

Answer (score 0):

in order to fix the problem I also have to indicate max value. So I used maximum value as $1,000,000 which is fit for my dataset.